# Rails - uniqueness of email

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, email-validation

In Rails, we can do uniqueness:true. However for email service providers like Google, it's possible to have:

```
myemail+123@gmail.com
my.email@gmail.com
myemail@gmail.com
```

And all of them are actually a single email. Is there any way (beside using Regex to check) to do the checking here?

Comment: I suppose I would still use a Regex. Why don't you want to use it if I might ask?

Comment: Well, I thought there would be some libraries out there to do it. Apparently devise also doesn't check till this level of uniqueness.

Comment: Not that I know of, but you might be right. This use case seems a bit tricky though, I'm not sure if you actually want your application to be flexible enough to recognise the above email addresses as the same address. If your Regex is not perfectly on spot, you might open a security hole.

Comment: Why do you want to do this in the first place? Just because GMail split their possible mail addresses like this, this does not exclude that with another provider similar addresses might indeed belong to different human beings.

Comment: Well, there are many reasons for this. But in my case, user can use only one email and register multiple times. You may say about email confirmation and so on, but it's an overkill for my case.

Comment: This can be helpful when dealing with spammy sign ups so it's a completely valid question. Also, the functionality described could be constrained to gmail.com.

Answer (score 0):

The part before the `@` symbol is called `local-part` and every email-related RFC defines it as an opaque value, which is an identifier for a mailbox. For example, [RFC-5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322):

> The local-part portion is a domain-dependent string.  In addresses,
> it is simply interpreted on the particular host as a name of a
> particular mailbox.

If you were to implement this custom handling of tags and dots, you'd be going against RFC. This is never a good idea.